# Rasterio resampling image to lower resolution error: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I am trying to downsample a raster image to a lower resolution using `rasterio.` I am running into an error about `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` and I can't seem to figure out the cause of the issue or how to resolve it. I was hoping someone could suggest how to fix this.

So here is the code that I am using

```
with rasterio.open('image.tif') as dataset:
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(dataset.height / 3.75, dataset.width / 3.75, dataset.count),
        resampling=Resampling.cubic
    )
```

So this error came up then. `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

I also tried to use an integer value as well.

```
with rasterio.open('../openaerialmaps_imagery/ghana-alog/5bb9323e9ed15b0006d24f34-accra - ghana 2018-10-06.tif') as dataset:
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(dataset.height / 4, dataset.width / 4, dataset.count),
        resampling=Resampling.cubic
    )
```

So I tried using a factor of 3.75(float) and a factor of 4(integer), but got the same error.

The dataset's datatype is identified as `('uint8', 'uint8', 'uint8')`. But I am not sure where to go on this issue?

Comment: Float division is the default in Python 3, so even if the width and height are divisible by 4 you still get a float.  Wrap those `out_shape` values in `int()`

Comment: Okay got it. Yeah, that worked. Thanks for helping with that. I was lost on how to proceed.

Comment: I am novice in Python and I realised the code prensent in this post but I have a problem to save my image with the new resolution... `data` is a numpy.ndarray object and it's impossible find the `data.Affine()` to apply `data.update` like this : with rasterio.open(path3) as MNT: # Import du MNT pour lui appliquer un masque et extraire les metadonnees du MNT out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(MNT, geo_shp, crop=True) out_meta = MNT.meta out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff", "height": out_image.shape[1], "width": out_image.shape[2], "transform": out_transform}) with rasterio.open(path_e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out_shape` can not have floating point values as numpy arrays can't have floating point shapes.

Either explicitly truncate or round the `out_shape` values or use integer division. Also, note that rasterio reads data in (bands, rows, cols) order and you are requesting a (rows, cols, bands) order array.

```
with rasterio.open('image.tif') as dataset:
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(dataset.count, dataset.height // 3.75, dataset.width // 3.75), # Integer division using //
        resampling=Resampling.cubic
    )
```